# C# EF 5.0 Adding Million Records to MySQL DB takes hours

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

Below is the code i am using to add records to database.I know I am calling saveChanges() everytime which is expensive, but if a call save changes once after all i might get duplicate key exception. So i am looking for any idea to make it better to improve performance keeping duplicate records in mind.

```
using (var db = new dbEntities())
{

    for (int i = 0; i < csvCustomers.Count; i++)
    {
        var csvCustomer = csvCustomers[i];
        dbcustomer customer = new dbcustomer() { ADDRESS = csvCustomer.ADDRESS, FIRSTNAME = csvCustomer.FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME = csvCustomer.LASTNAME, PHONE = csvCustomer.PHONE, ZIPCODE = csvCustomer.ZIP };
        try
        {
            dbzipcode z = db.dbzipcodes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ZIP == customer.ZIPCODE);
            //TODO: Handle if Zip Code not Found in DB
            if (z == null)
            {
                db.dbcustomers.Add(customer);
                throw new DbEntityValidationException("Zip code not found in database.");
            }
            customer.dbzipcode = z;
            z.dbcustomers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

One solution that i have in my mind is to add data in batches and then call db.SaveChanges() and in case of Exception reduces the batch size recursively for those records.

Comment: What if you save changes after the for statement?

Comment: Batching would help, but throw away the `DbContext` and create a new one for each batch, it will otherwise track (in memory) every row you touch or add until you do.  And only call `SaveChanges()` once per batch.

Comment: Have you tried any of https://stackoverflow.com/a/53558187/34092 ?

Comment: Just don't use EF to insert that amount of records.

Comment: @GertArnold what should i use ? Any link to point me in the right direction ?

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto it will fail even if one record is duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Using EF to insert huge #'s of records is going to incur a significant cost compared to more direct approaches, but there are a few considerations you can make to markedly improve performance.

Firstly, batching the requests with a save changes will be preferential to saving individual records, or attempting to commit all of the changes at once. You will need to deal with exceptions if/when a batch fails. (Possibly committing that batch one at a time to fully isolate duplicate rows)

Next, you can pre-cache your zip codes rather than looking it up each iteration. Don't load the entire entity, just cache the zip code and the ID into an in-memory list:
(If the zip code entity amounts to little more than this, then just load the entity)
    var zipCodes = db.dbzipcodes.Select(x => new {x.ZIPCODEID, x.ZIP}).ToList();

This will require a bit of extra attention when it comes to associating a zipcode to the customer within the batched calls since the zip code will initially not be known by the DbContext but may be known when the second customer for the same zip code is added.

To associate a zip code without loading it in a DbContext:

```
var customerZipCode = zipCodes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ZIP = customer.ZIPCODE);
// + exists check...
var zipCode = new dbzipcode { ZIPCODEID = customerZipCode.ZIPCODEID };
db.dbzipcodes.Attach(zipCode);
customer.dbzipcode = zipCode;
// ...
```

If you did load the entire zip code entity into the cached list, then the `var zipCode = new dbzipcode ...` is not needed, just attach the cached entity.

However, if in the batch that zip code has already been associated to the DbContext you will get an error, (regardless of whether you cached the entity or just the ID/Code) so you need to first check the dbContext in-memory zip codes:

```
var customerZipCode = zipCodes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ZIP = customer.ZIPCODE);
// + exists check...
var zipCode = db.dbzipcodes.Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ZIPCODEID == customerZipCode.ZIPCODEID) 
  ?? new dbzipcode { ZIPCODEID = customerZipCode.ZIPCODEID };
db.dbzipcodes.Attach(zipCode);
customer.dbzipcode = zipCode;
// ...
```

Lastly, EF tracks a lot of extra info in memory as the context so the other consideration along with batching would be to avoid using the same DbContext across all batches, rather opening a DbContext with each batch. As you add items and call SaveChanges across a DbContext, it is still tracking each entity that gets added. If you did batches of 1000 or so, the context would be tracking just that 1000 rather than 1000 then 2000, then 3000, etc. up to 5 Million rows.